# Sum based on different column from model in Power BI

Tags: sum, powerbi, sumifs

I have data from two tables modelled as follows:

[image]

[image]

my desired result is:

[image]

I've tried SUM(table1[balance],ALLEXCEPT(table1,table1[account])) - doesn't work

this may be simple, but PowerBi is evading me at this point...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple to solve it by with extra steps to complete it:

First, on your second table (I named it  "cust"), add a new column with the balance from your first table (I named it "acc"):

```
Balance = LOOKUPVALUE(acc[balance],acc[account ],cust[account])
```

**Cust**

[image]

Next, I will add a new column to `lookupvalue` on my "acc" table, follow by adding new column to return the `sum` value from my "cust" table:

```
sum = CALCULATE(SUM(cust[Balance]),FILTER(cust,cust[customer ]=EARLIER(acc[customer])))
```

**Acc**

[image]